# Moving between $Sp_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$ reps and $SL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ reps

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras, irreducible-representation

Say I have some irreducible $Sp_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$ representation, such as $\Gamma_{0,1,0,1}$.

Consider the subgroup of $Sp_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$ isomorphic to $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$, consisting of matrices of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
M&0\\ 
0&(M^{t})^{-1} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

with $M \in SL_n(\mathbb{C})$. What steps can I take to decompose my $Sp_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$ representation as a direct sum of irreducible $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ representations? Either by hand or by a program such as LiE. I believe $M \in SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ acts as $V \oplus V^*$,
where $V$ is the standard representation of $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $V^*$ is its dual.

Comment: This procedure is known as branching and can be quite complicated to compute in  general. LiE has a function called branch exactly for this.

Comment: @Callum Thank you! I'm looking at the branch function now, which looks like branch(vector, group $h$, restriction matrix $m$, group $g$). I would geuss that for my example (say $n=6$): my vector is [0,1,0,1], $h$ is A5, $g$ is C12. Is this true, and then what is $m$?

Comment: $m$ is the restriction matrix which is laid out  in the LiE manual but is I believe, roughly speaking, the matrix of the restriction of the original simple roots into your new ones

Comment: Also for $n=6$, $g$ will be $C6$ ($Sp_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$ is of type $C_n$) and $v$ must be a vector of length $6$

Comment: If anyone has any more guidance re: finding the restriction matrix for this example, I'd appreciate the help. In the meantime, I assume I need to learn what a root system is.

Comment: Or if anyone has a good reference for branching! with examples